# JQuery body background animation - bug in Chrome/Safari

Tags: jquery, css, google-chrome, safari

I'm getting some parts of background not changing color properly in Chorme and Safari. IE and FF works fine.

Code that does animation is:

```
$('body, div.piro_overlay').stop(true).animate({ backgroundColor: colors[currColor] }, animationDuration);
```

whole script is available at http://www.almadujmovic.com/scripts/ui_scripts.min.js

You can reproduce bug by going to http://www.almadujmovic.com/index.php?option=com_content&view=article&id=3&Itemid=4&lang=en and scrolling to bottom, wait for cca 10 seconds and then scroll half way up. Part of page will remain in old color, and other part will be animated.

Any idea how to solve it?

Comment: I've added an fullscreen div and animated his background. Now it's working!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed it by fitting div thru whole page, who is acting like a background, and then animating him.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this will work or not, but you could try setting a fixed background (one that doesn't scroll with the page) with the `background-attachment: fixed;` property in CSS.

I know it's meant for background images, but it's worth a try.